# How to add value to an array by index wise?

Tags: java

There is a String value Eg:('12560') and I need to put it into an array by index wise.

Eg : 
Input:

```
String x = "12560";
```

Output:

```
String arr[] = {"1","2","5","6","0"};
```

Comment: Downvoted because no attempt whatsoever to solve it yourself or to do any research. You are expected to do that before posting on SO, please see [ask], thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one line answer:

JAVA 8 and above:

```
x.split("");
```

JAVA 7 and below:

```
x.split("(?!^)");
```

Comment: And the most relevant one according to the OP's question.

Comment: Fixed it @Zabuza

Comment: Upvote. But note that its not more than a "copy" of the answer of the duplicate now :/

Comment: Didn't read the original post before answering it.. Also the OP may just see the first upvoted answer from the post and use it without reading the comments and not use the simplified form that java 8 provides. So this answer actually adds something. :P

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
String x = "12560"
char[] chars = x.toCharArray();
```

Comment: They want a String array

Comment: That is a `char[]` but OP seems to ask for `String[]`.

Comment: Not really clear, the requirement seems to be " i need to put it into an array by index wise."

Answer (score 0):

Something like this shall work.

Create a new String [] array, proceed with adding each character as a new string inside it.

```
     String x = "12560";

      String output [] = new String[x.length()];
      for(int i = 0 ; i < x.length() ; i++){
          output[i] = x.charAt(i)+"";
          System.out.println(output[i]);
      }
```

Output -

```
1
2
5
6
0
```

Answer (score -1):

This code is worked for me.

```
    //c is the user input value
    String c  = "12560";
    //create a String array to add final results
    String finArr[] = new String[c.split("").length];
    //put input value to an array by splitting
    String arr[] = c.split("");
    //add
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        finArr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<finArr.length;j++){
        System.out.println(finArr[j]);
    }
```

Comment: The "add-loop" is completely uncessary. The data is already in `arr`. Also, you are executing the split twice, once to get the length, once to get the data. But one execution is enough. Additionally, you should not go for a c-style array notation `Foo foo[]` but for Java-like `Foo[] foo` notation.